Locust Load Test - Fixed RPS
I'm testing API endpoints in which the test case is that in total 10 minutes I have to ramp up users linearly until the rps is >= 70 if rps greater than 70 and the current time is < 60 minutes then maintain in steady state for remaining time. My question is, is there a way I can take the current RPS and user count in every iteration? My code is
from locust import TaskSet,HttpUser, LoadTestShape

class Scan(TaskSet):
    @task
    def perf_scan(self):
        self.client.get(f“/api”)

class url(HttpUser):
    tasks = [Scan]

class CustomLoadShapeScenario2(LoadTestShape):
    def tick(self):
        total_time = 3600
        run_time = self.get_run_time()
        if RPS < 70 and run_time<total_time: # here for RPS I need a solution to extract from locust
            users = run_time//10
            spawn_rate = 1
        elif run_time<total_time:
            users = user_count # here for RPS I need a solution to extract from locust. It is the user_count until the if condition was satisfied
            spawn_rate = 1
        return (users, spawn_rate) 

Any code example or solution will be of great help.
I need a solution to extract current rps and user count for each iteration

@task is not defined.  what is this ?

the quotation marks around /api are incorrect syntax.

there are undefined variables and incorrect syntax in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

there is no get_run_time() method in the class CustomLoadShapeScenario2(LoadTestShape) class. so this will not work.

@D.L I have defined the @task in TaskSet Class. Also I removed the actual API endpoint and /api this I just typed it. The code above works perfectly fine. My question is that I need to extract the current RPS and use_count for every request. Right now I'm taking these values from the log file stats_history.csv but I don't want to do this. If you think this is not the correct logic can you please give me an example for the logic too? I'm pretty new to locust..
